# Magento 2 - Get tree of specific category, child categories and product collection

Tags: magento2

I have specific categorize and I want to create a menu from this specific categories with categories children and display product name.. example

```
Specific root categories
   subcategory
              product
              product
        subcategory
              product
              product
              product
              product
   subcategorie
              product
              product
        subcategory
              product
              product
              product
              product
              product
        subcategorie
              product
              product
              product
   subcategorie
        subcategorie
        subcategorie
   subcategorie
        subcategorie
        subcategorie
        subcategorie
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> en block class add

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;

class Menu extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
protected $categoryRepository;
protected $_categoryFactory;


public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
    CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
)
{
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getParentCategorie($categoryId)
{
    return $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
}

public function getSubcategories($categoryId)
{
    return $this->getParentCategorie($categoryId)->getChildrenCategories();
}

public function getCategoryName($categoryId)
{
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $categoryName = $category->getName();
    return $categoryName;
}

public function getCategoryProduts($categoryId)
{
    $collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId)->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc');
    return $collection;
}

/*public function getsubCategories($catId){
    $cat = $this->_categoryFactory->load($catId);
    $subcats = $cat->getChildren();
    $subcategories = array();
    foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid){
        $_subCategory = $this->_categoryFactory->load($subCatid);
        if($_subCategory->getIsActive()) {
            $subcategories[] = array('id'=>$_subCategory->getId(),'name'=>$_subCategory->getName()); 
        }
    }
    return $subcategories; 
}*/

    public function getCategory($categoryId)
{
    return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
}
}
```

> en phptml use

```
<?php $parent_category_id = 20 ?>
<?php $subCategories = $block->getSubcategories($parent_category_id) ?>
<b><?php echo $block->getCategoryName($parent_category_id); ?></b>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($subCategories as $subCategorie): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $subCategorie->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $subCategorie->getName() ?></a></li>
            <?php if($subCategorie->getProductCount() > 0): ?>
            <?php $productCollection = $block->getCategoryProduts($subCategorie->getId()); ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($productCollection as $_product): ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName()?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if ($subCategorie->hasChildren()):  ?>
                <?php $childSubCategories = $block->getSubcategories($subCategorie->getId()); ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($childSubCategories as $childSubCategorie): ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo $childSubCategorie->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $childSubCategorie->getName() ?></a></li>
                        <?php if($childSubCategorie->getProductCount() > 0): ?>
                            <?php $childproductCollection = $block->getCategoryProduts($childSubCategorie->getId()); ?>
                            <ul>
                                <?php foreach($childproductCollection as $_item): ?>
                                    <li><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_item->getName()?></a></li>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```